# FrameLayout 4:3 aspect ratio

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, android-framelayout

**Introduction**

I have implemented a camera into my application that takes 4:3 ratio images, here is my camera in XML

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageCapture">
</FrameLayout>
```

In my camera class I then call my surfaceview on this object:

```
public FrameLayout preview;
//,,,
preview = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageCapture);
//...
myCameraSurfaceView = new Surface(getActivity(), myCamera);
preview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
```

It all works very nicely, but!

**The problem**

My camera takes 4:3 photos, as shown below:

```
p.setPictureSize(bWidthFourThree, bHeightFourThree);
myCamera.setParameters(param);
```

So my captured image is a 4:3 photo which I want. **BUT** my camera preview (the framelayout/surfaceview implementation) wraps the whole screen.

**What I would like**

Now I know what the problem is, it wraps the screen because both width and height are match parent for the frame layout. What I would like is:

- Set the frame layout parameters according to bWidthFourThree,BHeightFourThree. However, between devices these variables can change due to different camera hardware etc so I cant hardcode the width and height. Also my SurfaceView for the camera is an inner class to the Camera class so I don't know how I can get the cameras resolution variables before creating the framelayout

any help is much appreciated, if any extra information is needed please let me know and Ill update this post

Comment: You don't have to have the FrameLayout in your xml, you can instance a new one and set your layout parameters (through FrameLayout.LayoutParams), so you can instance it only after you have the camera dimensions. After that, you can add the FrameLayout to another view (LinearLayout, i.e.).

Comment: Could you give me an example please, I understand what you mean just not how to implement it

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a FrameLayout before you have the variable values from the camera. Let's say that FrameLayout was going inside a LinearLayout. You would instance it and then set it's parameters, so:

```
//I used getContext(), but you can change it to yours
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
//The layout parameters must ALWAYS be related to the parent. So, if it's a LinearLayout, you'll use LinearLayout.LayoutParams
//Create the parameters using the dimensions you want
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bWidthFourThree, bHeightFourThree);
//Add your FrameLayout to the LinearLayout passing the parameters
yourLinearLayout.addView(frameLayout, layoutParams);
```

That way, you'll instantiate a FrameLayout and pass the camera dimensions to it AFTER you have them. After that, you can pass the image to your FrameLayout by adding the view (as you did).

Let me know if it helps you, and, if yes, remember to upvote/select as correct answer. If you have more questions, reply to this answer, cheers

Comment: I don't think this is possible, If i show you the file I think itll make more sense. Take a look at the readme.txt first https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4vL9wnJulKodmg4S0hyQ1NSSXc I really appreciate if you can help ive been stuck on this for a long time

Comment: Will take a look later on and I'll let you know, but from what I saw it is possible, why would you say it isn't?

Comment: bWidthFourThree and  bHeightFourThree are found in the surfaceview class, they are only assigned values inside the SurfaceCreated Method, so i cant get to them from the photo class

Comment: It seems I don't have access to your drive, so I cant see your code : /. Why don't you pass a FrameLayout to that method, in example, and use those values to instantiate it? Or make that method return a FrameLayout?

Comment: I understand what my problem is, its not the framelayout. I've been working on this for hours i am so close but so far. I made a question about it here because this one is not the problem please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353028/camera-orientation-and-preview-size

Comment: I'll take a look. Please, upvote this answer so others can see in the future, in case they face the same problem.